# ESlint no-multiple-template-root error message

Tags: vue.js, templates

I got this error message:

> [vue/no-multiple-template-root]
> The template root requires exactly one element.eslint-plugin-vue.

How do I fix it please?

Comment: Please edit to change the screaming title to normal voice. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you make any kind of research before posting your question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something like this

```html
<template>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</template>
```

change it into that

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

As explained here: https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-multiple-template-root.html